# Tiptap removes Vuetify packages in Nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, tiptap

I have a Nuxt project with Vuetify, and I want to use Tiptap as WYSIWYG for an input.
I follow Tiptap installation guide which is : `npm install @tiptap/vue-2 @tiptap/starter-kit`.
During the installation, some packages seem to be removed. As a result, after installation the app won't run. It emits an error of `Cannot find module 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'`, which I have researched, and found out that it caused by missing Vuetify packages that have been removed.
I respond to this by add Vuetify as a plugin with `vue add vuetify`.
Everything works again, but whenever I try to install any Tiptap Extension, the problem happens again.
There is an open source pre-defined plugin here https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/tiptap-vuetify that work just fine, but it doesn't meet my need.
Any advise in this particular stack?

Answer (score 1):

Well folks.
Fortunately, I have found the solution.
Post here in case someone run into the same problem.

I was using `yarn` as my package manager, but when I tried to install `tiptap`, I was stupid enough to just copy suggested command which uses `npm`.
Thus, `npm` takes over `yarn`, and start the process of adjusting everything inside the app.

So, just remember to stick with package manager that you chose to use when you initialized your app.